# Entering Thailand on a Visa Waiver when one has a single-entry visa

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, uk-citizens, thailand, visa-free-entry

I plan to travel round Southeast Asia, and I will obtain a 60-day single entry Thai Tourist Visa in advance. However, on my first entry to Thailand, I only intend to stay a week or so (certainly less than the 30-day visa exemption period). It is on my second entry I would be in need of the full 60 day visa. Is it possible to enter on a visa extemption even if one has a valid visa?

Comment: How are you exiting Thailand the first time?  The airline will want to see POOT (proof of onward travel). And immigration may want to it too, since you are claiming to leave quickly and then come back to use the visa.

Comment: @Tom I will be leaving overland. It is not possible to book my intended means of transport online in advance. Based on the wording of the appropriate Timatic entry, I doubt check-in staff will wish to see this, and if in the unlikely scenario they demand to see it to check me in, I'll shell out the £30 or so for a BKK-KUL flight and be done with it.

Comment: Airlines check for POOT quite regularly for flights to Thailand.

Comment: @Tom My options include:
1. Showing them the visa (not mentioning I won't be using it)
2. Explaining I'm leaving overland
3. Buying a throwaway bus ticket
4. Buying a throwaway flight ticket. 
#4 is guaranteed to work, and I see no reason to take pre-emptive action other than leaving plenty of time to check in.
I am extremely doubtful that Immigration will want to see POOT, as I am a British passport holder, with a place at university, and a perfectly plausible excuse for how I will depart the country. Of course, if necessary, I will take the same steps.

Comment: 2 & 3 don't work as POOT.  My advice is based on flying a dozen times a year to and from Thailand, for many years now.  But it is up to you to believe as you wish.

Comment: @Tom flying a dozen times a year makes it far more likely to be asked, does it not? In any case, I do not see what action you are suggesting I take. Any savings from buying a throwaway ticket in advance would be wiped out by the chance of not being asked for it. I will be at the airport early, and if necessary, I will spend the money for a throwaway ticket once I have exhausted all other possibilities. I do not anticipate that this will be necessary, but if proven wrong, I will still be 100% fine, on my flight, with my pocket ever so slightly lighter.

Comment: @Tom So if you're (legit) leaving overland, you need to buy a throwaway air ticket or get a visa? Timatic just says a return/onward ticket is needed, not that it has to be by air

Comment: @jacoman891 Just get a fully refundable ticket

Comment: @crazydre - airline tickets are the acceptable form  of POOT for Thailand, bus tickets are not.  Just the way it is.

Comment: @jacoman891 - my frequency of travel does not alter the rules for travel.  I have a multiple entry visa and still get asked for POOT if my return is beyond my allowable 90 days.

Comment: @Tom Is that actually stipulated in law (if so, can you link), or is it something airport ground staff makes up out of their own bottoms? I for one can't find anything online saying an onward air ticket is a strict requirement

Comment: @crazydre - it is airline practice not Thai law. But I am not going to argue further, go to TripAdvisor and you will lots of simular threads with the exact same point about POOT as I am mentioning.

Comment: A word of warning. The visa waiver overland is only available twice a year. Make sure you haven't had two overland entries this year.

Comment: [FlyOnward.com](https://www.FlyOnward.com) is a great way to secure real POOT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.

When presenting your passport, if the officer sees the visa, tell them you're only staying for two weeks this time, and will use your visa next time you enter, meaning you're only applying for a visa-free entry this time.

You will then get the usual entry stamp letting you stay for 30 days.

**During the inspection, make sure the visa isn't endorsed with a "used" stamp**

Comment: Actually "checking immediately" would already be too late... If the visa is stamped, oops, too bad. Your advice to communicate with the immigration officer is the most important part.